# Dealing with XmlTextWriter and null node

Tags: c#, xml, xmltextwriter

I have some code that create xml file on the fly. Sometimes the node has a value and sometimes not. I need to get open and closing tags `<hour>12:00</hour>` or `<hour></hour>` even there is no value but I can't find a solution. where the value is empty I am getting `<hour />`

```
XmlTextWriter writer = new XmlTextWriter(path + "/" + CustomerId + "/Data/" + CustomerId + ".xml", System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
writer.WriteStartDocument(true);
writer.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
writer.Indentation = 2;
writer.WriteStartElement("data");

if (paravalue == null || paravalue == "")
{
    writer.WriteStartElement(para);
    writer.WriteString("");
    writer.WriteEndElement();
}
else
{
    writer.WriteStartElement(para);
    writer.WriteString(paravalue);
    writer.WriteEndElement();
}
```

Comment: Allways need tags like: <hour>12:00</hour> and not <hour />

Comment: I'm not sure why you would need this. `<hour></hour>` and `<hour/>` are equivalent, and fully interchangeable!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`WriteFullEndElement`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlwriter.writefullendelement(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of `WriteEndElement`.

Comment: there is some way to avoid the line break?

Comment: Try calling `writer.WriteWhitespace("");` instead of `writer.WriteString("");` in the first branch.

Comment: get some error: Only white space characters should be used

Comment: mmmm now its ok i forget some space between " "